# Subtracting two dates to get hh:mm:ss

Tags: oracle

I am trying to subtract the END of an Event -START of an Event and get the time difference. I started by trying:

```
TO_CHAR(WXN_MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_CHAR(WXN_MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIME_DIF
```

However, this doesn't work.  I then tried:

```
(WXN_MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND - WXN_MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART) AS TIME_DIF
```

This gives me answers like 0.125.  How do I subtract these date fields and end up with a hh:mm:ss format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `mopend` and `mopstart` are both `date` columns, subtracting two dates return a difference in days.  If you want to format that into hours, minutes, and seconds, you'll need to do a bit of math.

```
with diffs as (
   select 0.125 diff_in_days from dual
)
select trunc( mod(diff_in_days * 24, 24) ) diff_in_hours,
       trunc( mod(diff_in_days * 24 * 60, 60) ) diff_in_mins,
       trunc( mod(diff_in_days * 24 * 60 * 60, 60) ) diff_in_secs
  from diffs;
```

An alternative would be to use an `interval` and extract the individual components

```
with diffs as (
   select numtodsinterval( 0.125, 'day' ) diff_interval from dual
)
select extract( hour from diff_interval ) diff_in_hours,
       extract( minute from diff_interval ) diff_in_mins,
       extract( second from diff_interval ) diff_in_secs
  from diffs;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try

```
TO_DATE((WXN_MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND - WXN_MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART), 
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS TIME_DIF
```

This should work. (I don't have any oracle DB right now)

Comment: Subtracting two dates returns a `number`.  You can't convert a `number` to a date using that format.

Comment: Right. But as I said - no DB right now. Anyway - to_char should work. And tommorow will try, just to correct the answer.

Comment: Sure, you can `to_char` a number.  But not with a date format mask.  You could convert the number 0.125 into the string '0.125'.  But `to_char` has no idea that 0.125 is in units of days or how to convert days to an 'hh24:mi:ss' format.